# Python Selenium - Timeout Exception

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, timeout

I'm using selenium to get the html for this site: 
`http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/us`

I'm using selenium because this site only gives you all the html if you scroll down. However when I run this code:

```
 # Open the Driver
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

#create a list to store the htmls
master_lst = []

#looping through the times of india urls
for url in urls[:3]:

#make the driver the the url
driver.get(url)
#this is to scroll down twelve time
for i in range(12):
    # wait 5 seconds
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

html_source = driver.page_source
data = Beautifulsoup(html_source, 'lxml')
master_lst.append(data)
```

I get this error: 
`TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.004`

I've tried to change the sleep times and the times I scroll down to no avail. 
I've seen similar question in here but none that address this kind of problem. 
Let me know what you all think!
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to *adjust the script timeout*:

```
driver.set_script_timeout(10)
```

Comment: Thanks you!!! Just attaching another useful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941260/what-does-selenium-set-script-timeoutn-do-and-how-is-it-different-from-driver