# What does Selenium .set_script_timeout(n) do and how is it different from driver.set_page_load_timeout(n)?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, pageloadtimeout, setscripttimeout

In context of python selenium, I don't quite understand the exact difference of `driver.set_page_load_timeout(n)` VS. `driver.set_script_timeout(n)`. Both seem to be used interchangeable to set a timeout to load an URL via `driver.get(URL)`, but sometimes also together.

**Scenario 1**:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
website = driver.get(URL)
results = do_magic(driver, URL)
```

**Scenario 2**:

```
driver.set_script_timeout(5)
website = driver.get(URL)
results = do_magic(driver, URL)
```

**How do both scenarios differ? Which situations trigger a timeout in one but not the other scenario?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the *Selenium-Python API Docs* `set_page_load_timeout(n)` and `set_script_timeout(n)` both are *timeout* methods which are used to configure the *webdriver* instance to abide by during the program execution.

### set_page_load_timeout(time_to_wait)

[**`set_page_load_timeout(time_to_wait)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout) sets the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error and is defined as :

```
    def set_page_load_timeout(self, time_to_wait):
    """
    Set the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete
       before throwing an error.

    :Args:
     - time_to_wait: The amount of time to wait

    :Usage:
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
    """
    try:
        self.execute(Command.SET_TIMEOUTS, {
        'pageLoad': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
    except WebDriverException:
        self.execute(Command.SET_TIMEOUTS, {
        'ms': float(time_to_wait) * 1000,
        'type': 'page load'})
```

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [**`set_page_load_timeout`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227#47695227)

### set_script_timeout(time_to_wait)

[**`set_script_timeout(time_to_wait)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_script_timeout) sets the amount of time that the script should wait during an [`execute_async_script`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/event_firing_webdriver.html#EventFiringWebDriver.execute_async_script) (**Javascript** / **AJAX Call**) call before throwing an error and is defined as :

```
    def set_script_timeout(self, time_to_wait):
    """
    Set the amount of time that the script should wait during an
       execute_async_script call before throwing an error.

    :Args:
     - time_to_wait: The amount of time to wait (in seconds)

    :Usage:
        driver.set_script_timeout(30)
    """
    if self.w3c:
        self.execute(Command.SET_TIMEOUTS, {
        'script': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
    else:
        self.execute(Command.SET_SCRIPT_TIMEOUT, {
        'ms': float(time_to_wait) * 1000})
```

Comment: So this basically means that set_script_timeout does not do anything if there is no execute_async_script call?

Comment: Yeap, that's how it is implemented.

Comment: sorry for the delay DB