# Selenium loading, but not printing all HTML

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I am attempting to use Python and Selenium to web-scrape dynamically loaded data from a website. The problem is, only about half of the data is being reported as present, when in reality it all should be there. Even after using pauses before printing out all the page content, or simple find element by class searches, there seems to be no solution. The URL of the site is https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nfl-football/consensus/?date=20180909. As you can see, there are 13 main sections, however I am only able to retrieve data from the first four games. To best show the problem I'll attach the code for printing the inner-HTML for the entire page to show the discrepancies between the loaded and non-loaded data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

url = "https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nfl-football/consensus/?date=20180909"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
print(driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerText;"))
```

**EDIT**:
The problem is not the wait time, for I am running it line by line and fully waiting for it to load. It appears the problem boild down to selenium not grabbing all the JS loaded text on the page, as seen by the console output in the answer below.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `document.documentElement.innerHTML` ? or maybe `document.body.innerHTML` ?

Comment: @pguardiario Why are you posting to exact duplicate comments?

Comment: Those are actually slightly different. I recommend using `document.body.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

> This solution is **only** worth to consider **if** there are lots of WebDriverWait calls
>   and given the interest in reduced runtime - **else** go for DebanjanB's
>   approach

You need to wait some time to let your html load completely. Also, you can set a [timeout](http:///what-does-selenium-set-script-timeoutn-do-and-how-is-it-different-from-driver) for script execution. To add a unconditional wait to `driver.get(URL`) in selenium, `driver.set_page_load_timeout(n)` with `n = time/seconds` and loop:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(n)         # Set timeout of n seconds for page load
loading_finished = 0                    # Set flag to 0
while loading_finished == 0:            # Repeat while flag = 0
    try:
       sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.5))  # wait some time
       website = driver.get(URL)        # try to load for n seconds
       loading_finished = 1             # Set flag to 1 and exit while loop
       logger.info("website loaded")    # Indicate load success
    except:
       logger.warn("timeout - retry")   # Indicate load fail
else:                                   # If flag == 1
    driver.set_script_timeout(n)        # Set timeout of n seconds for script  
    script_finished = 0                 # Set flag to 0
    while script_finished == 0          # Second loop
       try:
          print driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerText;")       
          script_finished = 1           # Set flag to 1
          logger.info("script done")    # Indicate script done
       except:                          
          logger.warn("script timeout") 
    else:
        logger.info("if you're still missing html here, increase timeout")
```

Comment: use WebDriverWait, not this.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed though, but the problem is still present in the console output. But for the first 4 games, all of the wager data is retrieved, however for the next 9 games, only the team names and game start times are return, when looking at the actual page, all elements are present and loaded by the JS.

Comment: taking into account that you are executing a script, you could `driver.set_script_timeout(n)` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941260) - I have updated my answer

Comment: Great thought, but still not returning the same data for each div.

Comment: admittedly, my attempt now looks length and ugly - did you try the solution of @DebanjanB

Comment: Yes I did, but look at the difference in data retrieved in each block (there is a "/" separating each block). Although all the elements are present on the page, selenium is only "seeing" and being able to retrieve half of them.

Answer (score 1):

@sudonym's analysis was in the right direction. You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be visible* before you attempt to extract them through **`execute_script()`** method as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  url = "https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nfl-football/consensus/?date=20180909"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get(url)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[contains(.,'USA - National Football League')]//following::section//span[3]")))
  print(driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerText;"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  SPORTSBOOK REVIEW
  Home
  Best Sportsbooks
  Rating Guide
  Blacklist
  Bonuses
  BETTING ODDS
  FREE PICKS
  Sports Picks
  NFL
  College Football
  NBA
  NCAAB
  MLB
  NHL
  More Sports
  How to Bet
  Tools
  FORUM
  Home
  Players Talk
  Sportsbooks & Industry
  Newbie Forum
  Handicapper Think Tank
  David Malinsky's Point Blank
  Service Plays
  Bitcoin Sports Betting
  NBA Betting
  NFL Betting
  NCAAF Betting
  MLB Betting
  NHL Betting
  CONTESTS
  EARN BETPOINTS
  What Are Betpoints?
  SBR Sportsbook
  SBR Casino
  SBR Racebook
  SBR Poker
  SBR Store
  Today
  NFL
  NBA
  NHL
  MLB
  College Football
  NCAA Basketball
  Soccer
  Soccer Odds
  Major League Soccer
  UEFA Champions League
  UEFA Nations League
  UEFA Europa League
  English Premier League
  World Cup 2022
  Tennis
  Tennis Odds
  ATP
  WTA
  UFC
  Boxing
  More Sports
  CFL
  WNBA
  AFL
  Betting Odds/NFL Odds/Consensus
  TODAY
  |
  YESTERDAY
  |
  DATE
  ?
  Login
  ?
  Settings
  ?
  Bet Tracker
  ?
  Bet Card
  ?
  Favorites
  NFL Consensus for Sep 09, 2018
  USA - National Football League
  Sunday Sep 09, 2018
  01:00 PM
  /
  Pittsburgh vs Cleveland
  453
  Pittsburgh
  454
  Cleveland
  Current Line
  -3½+105
  +3½-115
  Wagers Placed
  10040
  54.07%
  8530
  45.93%
  Amount Wagered
  $381,520.00
  56.10%
  $298,550.00
  43.90%
  Average Bet Size
  $38.00
  $35.00
  SBR Contest Best Bets
  22
  9
  01:00 PM
  /
  San Francisco vs Minnesota
  455
  San Francisco
  456
  Minnesota
  Current Line
  +6-102
  -6-108
  Wagers Placed
  6250
  41.25%
  8900
  58.75%
  Amount Wagered
  $175,000.00
  29.50%
  $418,300.00
  70.50%
  Average Bet Size
  $28.00
  $47.00
  SBR Contest Best Bets
  5
  19
  01:00 PM
  /
  Cincinnati vs Indianapolis
  457
  Cincinnati
  458
  Indianapolis
  Current Line
  -1-104
  +1-106
  Wagers Placed
  11640
  66.36%
  5900
  33.64%
  Amount Wagered
  $1,338,600.00
  85.65%
  $224,200.00
  14.35%
  Average Bet Size
  $115.00
  $38.00
  SBR Contest Best Bets
  23
  12
  01:00 PM
  /
  Buffalo vs Baltimore
  459
  Buffalo
  460
  Baltimore
  Current Line
  +7½-103
  -7½-107
  Wagers Placed
  5220
  33.83%
  10210
  66.17%
  Amount Wagered
  $78,300.00
  16.79%
  $387,980.00
  83.21%
  Average Bet Size
  $15.00
  $38.00
  SBR Contest Best Bets
  5
  17
  01:00 PM
  /
  Jacksonville vs N.Y. Giants
  461
  Jacksonville
  462
  N.Y. Giants
  01:00 PM
  /
  Tampa Bay vs New Orleans
  463
  Tampa Bay
  464
  New Orleans
  01:00 PM
  /
  Houston vs New England
  465
  Houston
  466
  New England
  01:00 PM
  /
  Tennessee vs Miami
  467
  Tennessee
  468
  Miami
  04:05 PM
  /
  Kansas City vs L.A. Chargers
  469
  Kansas City
  470
  L.A. Chargers
  04:25 PM
  /
  Seattle vs Denver
  471
  Seattle
  472
  Denver
  04:25 PM
  /
  Dallas vs Carolina
  473
  Dallas
  474
  Carolina
  04:25 PM
  /
  Washington vs Arizona
  475
  Washington
  476
  Arizona
  08:20 PM
  /
  Chicago vs Green Bay
  477
  Chicago
  478
  Green Bay
  Media
  Site Map
  Terms of use
  Contact Us
  Privacy Policy
  DMCA
  18+. Gamble Responsibly.
  © Sportsbook Review. All Rights Reserved.
  ```

Comment: actually this is the way to go for OP's setup. my reason to not do it this way was that for my use case, there have been so many `WebDriverWait.until()` calls that the execution time went off into infinity. I decided to just get `driver.page_source()` once and do the rest with BS/lxml.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed though, but the problem is still present in the console output. But for the first 4 games, all of the wager data is retrieved, however for the next 9 games, only the team names and game start times are return, when looking at the actual page, all elements are present and loaded by the JS.