# stop page loading with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

At this time, my script will check multiple url if some 5 different type of keywords are present in the webpage. Depending of which keyword is found or not, it will output "ok" or "no".

I use `set_page_load_timeout(30)` to avoid infinite load of a url.

Problem : some webpages doesn't load fully before timeout (even if it's a "very" long timeout). But I can see visually (no headless) that the page is loaded. At least it could check the keywords in the webpage but it doesn't and after timeout, it display "fail" and the scrape saying "no" doesn't show to the final output.

So I don't want to put an except after 30 seconds but I want to stop loading the page after 30 seconds and takes what it can be taken.

My code :

```
# coding=utf-8
import re

sites=[]

keywords_1=[]
keywords_2=[]
keywords_3=[]
keywords_4=[]
keywords_5=[]

import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
import urllib.parse
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


def reader3(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        # creating a csv reader object
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # extracting field names through first row
        # extracting each data row one by one
        for row in csvreader:
            sites.append(str(row[0]).lower())
try:
    reader3("data/script/filter_domain_OUTPUT.csv")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()
exc=[]
def reader3(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        # creating a csv reader object
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # extracting field names through first row
        # extracting each data row one by one
        for row in csvreader:
            exc.append(str(row[0]).lower())
try:
    reader3("data/script/checking_EXCLUDE.csv")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()
def reader2(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        # creating a csv reader object
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        # extracting field names through first row
        # extracting each data row one by one
        for row in csvreader:
            keywords_1.append(str(row[0]).lower())
            keywords_2.append(str(row[1]).lower())
            keywords_3.append(str(row[2]).lower())
            keywords_4.append(str(row[3]).lower())
            keywords_5.append(str(row[4]).lower())

try:
    reader2("data/script/checking_KEYWORD.csv")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit()


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
#chrome_options.headless = True

chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
chrome_options.add_argument('enable-automation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
for site in sites:
    try:
        status_1 = "no"
        status_2 = "no"
        status_3 = "no"
        status_4 = "no"
        status_5 = "no"
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        today = date.today()
        print("[" + current_time + "] " + str(site))
        if 'http' in site:
            driver.get(site)
        else:
            driver.get("http://" + site)
        r=str(driver.page_source).lower()
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
        for keyword_1 in keywords_1:
            if keyword_1 in r:
                status_1="ok"
                print("home -> " +str(keyword_1))
                break

        for keyword_2 in keywords_2:
            if keyword_2 in r:
                status_2="ok"
                print("home -> " +str(keyword_2))
                break

        for keyword_3 in keywords_3:
            if keyword_3 in r:
                status_3="ok"
                print("home -> " +str(keyword_3))
                break

        for keyword_4 in keywords_4:
            if keyword_4 in r:
                status_4="ok"
                print("home -> " +str(keyword_4))
                break
        for keyword_5 in keywords_5:
            if keyword_5 in r:
                status_5="ok"
                print("Home ->" +str(keyword_5))
                break 
        with open('data/script/checking_OUTPUT.csv', mode='a') as employee_file:
            employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,lineterminator='\n')
            write=[site,status_1,status_2,status_3,status_4,status_5]
            employee_writer.writerow(write)
            
        
    except Exception as e:
        #driver.delete_all_cookies()
        print("Fail")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/#:~:text=Defines%20the%20current%20session's%20page,loading%20takes%20lot%20of%20time](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/#:%7E:text=Defines%20the%20current%20session%27s%20page,loading%20takes%20lot%20of%20time).

```
    chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

use page loading strategy Eager to wait only till initial html is loaded , you can also use none , but make sure you have explicit/implicit waits for elements if timing issue comes up

### In python its working wierdly only the diseried capability is working

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
# caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  Waits for full page load
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, options=options)




url = 'https://www.gm-trucks.com/'


driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
print("hi")
input()
```

Or :

```
options = Options()

options.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy", "none")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

## Update

The documentation is updated as per selenium 4.0.0-alpha-7

so use above solution or update to selenium v4 for future protection

```
  pip install selenium==4.0.0.a7
```

**Bug**

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/issues/627

Comment: I'm already using chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
but there is no effect

Comment: @Mathieu what is the issue you face the code doesn't go beyond driver.get ?

Comment: If it doesn't find the word, it output "no". But in the case the url didn't fully loaded, it fails. That's the issue. Because most of the time it should be able to search for a word, even if the full page is not loaded

Comment: Example: https://www.gm-trucks.com/ => It took more than the timeout, so it fails evn if the page is 99% loaded (visually)

Comment: @Mathieu updated the answer its working wierdly only desired capability is working

Comment: @Mathieu updated the answer , the documenation is per v4 of selenium so update the version to 4 or use the caps as mentioned in answer

Comment: it says : NameError: name 'ChromeOptions' is not defined

Comment: @Mathieu change it to Options , i just copy pasted my code which had options as chromeoptions

Answer (score 0):

To start with, ideally `set_page_load_timeout()` and `page_load_strategy = 'none'` shouldn't be clubbed up together.

### set_page_load_timeout()

[set_page_load_timeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941260/what-does-selenium-set-script-timeoutn-do-and-how-is-it-different-from-driver/48941597#48941597) set the amount of time to wait for a page load to complete before throwing an error.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to set the timeout of 'driver.get' for python selenium 3.8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227#47695227)

---

### page_load_strategy

[`page_load_strategy = 'none'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628) causes [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to return immediately after the initial page content is fully received (html content downloaded).

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to set the timeout of 'driver.get' for python selenium 3.8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322165/dont-wait-for-a-page-to-load-using-selenium-in-python/46339092#46339092)